# how to get Azure point-to-site client to connect to an Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have created an Azure virtual network with point-to-site connectivity enabled.

The point-to-site address space is 10.0.0.0/24 (10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.25).

The virtual network address space is 10.0.1.0/24 (10.0.1.4 - 10.0.1.254).

I added an Azure VM, and it is assigned an IP of 10.0.1.4.

I created the client VPN package and installed it on a machine.  It creates a PPP adapter with an IP address 10.0.0.1.

As a result I can't ping / connect to from the client 10.0.0.1 to the VM 10.0.1.4.

How should this work?  Do I need some other routing or should I have somehow ended up with the client and VM in the same subnet?

Should I have set up DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple - Windows VMs have default Firewall enabled (as do all default WIndows Server Installations). And this **Windows Firewall** blocks ICMP packets (which are the PING) packets.

You can easily test the connectivity to the VM by simply trying remote desktop to the targeted VM. Or disable the Windows Firewall.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of that but for some reason dismissed the idea.  I exposed a resource from my VM and was able to connect, so all good.